How to fix vscode issue on Ubuntu24.04?
After I upgrade to ubuntu24.04 , my vscode has many issues:

Can not use console in vscode when maxixum the vscode window
Can not open multiple vscode window
Other issues


https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/212430

